# Clone Div and append to iframe

Tags: javascript, clonenode

I'm attempting to get elements from a form so that the results can be styled and printed from an iframe. Here is the code I'm using:

```
  const printButton = document.getElementById('print-quiz');
  var clone = document.querySelector('.quiz_results').cloneNode( true );
  printButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
    this.event = event;
  // New HTML page
  const user = "<table><tr><td>" + document.querySelector('.quiz_results').appendChild(clone) + "</td></tr></table>";
  const printHtml = `<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Printed Quiz</title></head><body>${user}</body></html>`; 
  // get the iframe
  let iFrame = document.getElementById('print-quiz');
  iFrame.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = printHtml;
  iFrame.focus();
  iFrame.contentWindow.print();
});
```

All is well except, document.querySelector('.quiz_results').appendChild(clone) returns [object HTMLDivElement]

How can I modify my code to duplicate the div class (.quiz_results) and its inner contents into the html results iframe? I've been at this for a while and appreciate your assistance.

Comment: `iFrame` and `printButton` have same `id`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can clone an element to another document. Although just for printing you could have used the `outerHTML` (or `innerHTML`) property.

Your mistake was adding an `HTMLElement` to `string`. You should either append element to element, or concatenate string to another.

A working copy: https://jsfiddle.net/w04h9psd/

```js
const printButton = document.getElementById('print-quiz');
var clone = document.querySelector('.quiz_results').cloneNode(true);
printButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
  this.event = event;
  // New HTML page
  const user = "<table><tr><td id='user-container'></td></tr></table>";
  const printHtml = `<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Printed Quiz</title></head><body>${user}</body></html>`;
  // get the iframe
  let iFrame = document.getElementById('print-iframe');
  iFrame.contentDocument.body.innerHTML = printHtml;
  iFrame.contentDocument.getElementById("user-container").append(clone)

  iFrame.focus();
  iFrame.contentWindow.print();
});
```

```html
<button id="print-quiz">print quiz</button>
<div class="quiz_results">quiz_results: 100, 30, 60</div>
<iframe id="print-iframe"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you for this super-helpful working copy. Have a spectacular day!